# Is it safe to use lseek() when reading from Proc-FS files second time

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, seek, procfs

1. Is it safe to use `lseek(fd,0)` and then `read(fd,buf)` for `/proc/stat` file instead of reopening it to get updated contents of this file next time?
2. And what does the `mmap()` call after opening this file really do (see below)?

The problem I am encountering is that `top` reports way too low CPU usage (10% vs 100% for software interrupts). The `strace` tool indicates that `top` does not reopen this file but instead lseeks to beginning and reads it once again. And somehow the contents which are read from this file next time does not match with what I would get when I run cat for `/proc/stat` file alone.

Also If I run top and cat `/proc/stat` in a loop at the same time then `top` starts to report correct CPU-Usage.

One more difference I spot is that `top` uses `mmap()` call right after opening the `/proc/stat` file, while `cat` does not do that. I am not sure if this also could be related with my problem (because `filesdes=-1` here):

```
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7b37649000
```

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.1 Desktop edition with 2.6.32-27-server image. The CPU is Intel Q6600.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very interesting what you ask... I start checking in my machine but I don't see differences between cat /proc/stat and execute top. Anyway, I'm at work and I'm not totally 'free' to make tests.

The way you describe to 'refresh' the opened file to read new data is correct... in case of a [f|l]seek() call to the end and then to the beginning of the file will update the EOF and new data will be read.

I don't think that the mmap() call will cause the problem you mentioned, it could make the read faster, but nothing else (I'm not 100% sure).

I would suggest you to make a small app in C that open /proc/stat, read it, seek it and read it again to see how it's updated, also if you have some stress test to do could be useful.

Now, answering your real questions:

1. Yes, AFAIK it's sure because you will be 'waiting' for new data on the file and it should be better than open and close the file all the time.
2. It maps a file to the process address space, here are some info and examples:

http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/mmap-tutorial-c-c-511265/

Comment: That is true about lseek. It seems that htop is implemented to reopen /proc/stat file each time before reading it, but in the meantime htop also reports invalid cpu-usage. So we can probably rule out lseek().

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66225418/14393739), it is not possible to memory map a file from the */proc* virtual file system. You would get an **EIO** error from `mmap()`.
The optimal way to avoid a systematic `open/read/close`, is to simply open the file once and seek to the beginning to read its content again. Updated data are returned.
Here is an example program reading */proc/meminfo* every second:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MEMINFO_FNAME "/proc/meminfo"

int read_file(int fd)
{
  int rc;
  char buffer[512];
  off_t off;

  off = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
  if (off == (off_t)-1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lseek(%s): '%m' (%d)\n", MEMINFO_FNAME, errno);
    return -1;
  }

  do {

    rc = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (rc > 0) {
      buffer[rc] = '\0';
      printf("%s", buffer);
    }
    
  } while(rc > 0);

  return rc;
}

int main(void)
{
  int fd;
  int rc;

  // Open the file
  fd = open(MEMINFO_FNAME, O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "open(%s): '%m' (%d)\n", MEMINFO_FNAME, errno);
    return 1;
  }

  do {
    printf("==========\n");
    rc = read_file(fd);
    sleep(1);
  } while(rc == 0);

  close(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

The execution shows varying values after each reads in the file:

```
$ gcc meminfo.c -o meminfo
$ ./meminfo
==========
MemTotal:       131927796 kB
MemFree:         9305304 kB
MemAvailable:   125498348 kB
Buffers:        53300112 kB
[...]
==========
MemTotal:       131927796 kB
MemFree:         9323984 kB
MemAvailable:   125517048 kB
Buffers:        53300112 kB
[...]
==========
MemTotal:       131927796 kB
MemFree:         9324236 kB
MemAvailable:   125517300 kB
Buffers:        53300120 kB
[...]
```

**N.B.**: Depending on the average size of the file which is monitored, the size of the read buffer can be adapted to have only one call to `read()`.